# RegEx not working on DocuSign for text validation

Tags: c#, regex, docusignapi

I created a RegEx on my textbox to validate an exact text (case-insensitive) on a DocuSign envelope: ***^(?i)(Lu, approuvé 1000 parts)$***

When opening the envelope, if I type the correct or wrong text the textbox stray red-highlighted. Thus I cannot approve my envelope, and my RegEx error message is even not displayed (same behaviour if no content provided).

On the [DocuSign data validation guide](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-data-validation-for-text-fields), it is said that we can use [RegexStorm.NET](http://regexstorm.net/tester) to test our RegEx. I did it and it works.

It is also stated in the documentation that DocuSign uses the .NET RegEx engine. I did a test in .NET and once again my RegEx works (see [my .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7JSHeZ)).

If I remove `(?i)` from my RegEx it works, but I need case-insensitive.

It seems there is a problem DocuSign-side with RegEx.

Any idea how can I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure the spaces are regular spaces? Try `^(?i)(Lu,\s+approuvé\s+1000\s+parts)$`

Comment: Unfortunately same behaviour. However if I remove `(?i)` from my RegEx it works, but I need case-insensitive check.

Comment: Strange. Try putting the modifier at the start, `(?i)^(Lu,\s+approuvé\s+1000\s+parts)$`, or try a modifier group, `(?i:^(Lu,\s+approuvé\s+1000\s+parts)$)`

Comment: Both work on RegexStorm.NET and in my .NET Fiddle, but in DocuSign it does not, and worst the correct case version now fails :(

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is indeed a problem from the DocuSign parser, I posted my workaround in my answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from the DocuSign support and they agreed that the problem is from their side and are investigating at it.

What I did as a workaround is in my text I replace each character with all its forms (lower/upper/accent) like that for the text "approuvé": `^[aA][pP][pP][rR][oO][uU][vV][éÉeE]$`

That works like a charm but this is not very friendly to write, so I wrote some code to automate the translation of my texts into this kind of RegEx :

```
/// <summary>
/// Set a regular expression to the Text Tab
/// </summary>
/// <param name="textTab">Text Tab</param>
/// <param name="text">Text which will be converted into the regular expression</param>
private void SetRegex(TextTab textTab, string text)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        var regex = GetRegExWithoutCasse(text);
        textTab.ValidationPattern = regex;
        textTab.ValidationMessage = string.Format("Please type: {0}", text);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Get the RegEx associated to the text without casing-check
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">Text to check</param>
/// <returns>Regular expression</returns>
private string GetRegExWithoutCasse(string text)
{
    var result = string.Empty;
    foreach (var letter in text.Select(i => i.ToString()))
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(letter, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$"))
            result += "[" + letter.ToLower() + letter.ToUpper() + "]";
        else
        {
            var textWithoutDiacritics = RemoveDiacritics(letter);
            if (textWithoutDiacritics != letter)
                result += "[" + textWithoutDiacritics.ToLower() + textWithoutDiacritics.ToUpper() + letter.ToLower() + letter.ToUpper() + "]";
            else
                result += letter.ToString();
        }
    }

    return "^" + result + "$";
}

/// <summary>
/// Remove diacritics from text
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">Text</param>
/// <returns>Clean text</returns>
private string RemoveDiacritics(string text)
{
    var tempBytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-8").GetBytes(text);
    var asciiStr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tempBytes);
    return asciiStr;
}
```